# Can some Gnome themes slow down the computer?

Tags: linux, gnome

I was wondering if it is possible that some gnome themes can slow down the computer. Do they have any impact on performance? Will it use more resources, such as CPU and RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - more complex desktop images, fonts and visual effects will all require more processing and memory.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically Yes - However the slowness is not noticeable as it will be in Milli seconds.